# Issues using the timing threading feature

Tags: python

to run a section of code every three seconds

```
send_every_3_secs(circ_attack, data)
```

circ_attack is an instance, data is a str

```
def send_every_3_secs(circ_attack, data):
    circ_attack.streamData(1, data)
    threading.Timer(3.0, send_every_3_secs(circ_attack, data)).start()
```

the issue i am having is here, i get a long error message just containing :

```
  File "tor.py", line 570, in send_every_3_secs
    threading.Timer(3.0, send_every_3_secs(circ_attack, data)).start()
  File "tor.py", line 570, in send_every_3_secs
    threading.Timer(3.0, send_every_3_secs(circ_attack, data)).start()
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the arguments to `send_every_3_secs` using the `args` keyword parameter:

```
def send_every_3_secs(circ_attack, data):
    circ_attack.streamData(1, data)
    threading.Timer(3.0, send_every_3_secs, args=(circ_attack, data)).start()
```

When you pass `send_every_3_secs(circ_attack, data)` the function gets called first and its return value is passed to `threading.Timer`. But since `send_every_3_secs` is calling itself, you run into a RuntimeError: "maximum recursion depth exceeded" since none of the calls ever actually finish.